# Cannot add variogram plot exported from scikit-gstat into poltly as subplot using add_trace function

Tags: python, plotly, subplot, scikits

I run into trouble trying to add variogram graph from SciKit GStat as a subplot in plotly.

The error is describe as The 'data' property is a tuple of trace instances.
I'm not sure if it's some error in make_subplots specs, but I have no idea how to fix it.

```
The 'data' property is a tuple of trace instances
    that may be specified as:
      - A list or tuple of trace instances
        (e.g. [Scatter(...), Bar(...)])
      - A single trace instance
        (e.g. Scatter(...), Bar(...), etc.)
      - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties where:
        - The 'type' property specifies the trace type
            One of: ['bar', 'barpolar', 'box', 'candlestick',
                     'carpet', 'choropleth', 'choroplethmapbox',
                     'cone', 'contour', 'contourcarpet',
                     'densitymapbox', 'funnel', 'funnelarea',
                     'heatmap', 'heatmapgl', 'histogram',
                     'histogram2d', 'histogram2dcontour', 'icicle',
                     'image', 'indicator', 'isosurface', 'mesh3d',
                     'ohlc', 'parcats', 'parcoords', 'pie',
                     'pointcloud', 'sankey', 'scatter',
                     'scatter3d', 'scattercarpet', 'scattergeo',
                     'scattergl', 'scattermapbox', 'scatterpolar',
                     'scatterpolargl', 'scattersmith',
                     'scatterternary', 'splom', 'streamtube',
                     'sunburst', 'surface', 'table', 'treemap',
                     'violin', 'volume', 'waterfall']
        - All remaining properties are passed to the constructor of
          the specified trace type
        (e.g. [{'type': 'scatter', ...}, {'type': 'bar, ...}])
```

Example script:

```
import pandas as pd
import skgstat as skg
from skgstat.plotting import backend
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=1,cols=2,
                           specs=[[{'type':'scene'},{'type':'xy'}]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[350539.3, 350536.1, 350533.2, 350530.4, 350527.6],
                  'Y':[4212487.5, 4212483.2, 4212478.8, 4212474.1, 4212469.5],
                  'Z':[1765.52, 1765.54, 1765.54, 1765.47, 1765.42],
                  'R':[12.95, 13.42, 14.48, 14.58, 14.16]})
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(x=df.X.values, y=df.Y.values, z=df.Z.values)

backend('plotly')
V1 = skg.Variogram(df[["X", "Y", "Z"]].values, df.R.values,
                       estimator='matheron', n_lags=10, model='gaussian')
trace2 = V1.plot()
fig.add_trace(trace1,1,1)
fig.add_trace(trace2,1,2)
fig.show()
```

I'm able to open both maps by run

```
fig.add_trace(trace1,1,1)
fig.show()
```

and

```
trace2.show()
```

but

```
fig.add_trace(trace2,1,2)
fig.show()
```

will fail

Comment: I don't usually use skgstat so my comments may not be accurate. As far as I read the backend section of the [official reference](https://scikit-gstat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/tutorial_04_plotting.html?highlight=backend#backend), it is only expressed using the plotly graph engine and not plotly to the internal structure. The content of the object obtained by changing the backend in the official [reference example](https://scikit-gstat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/variogram.html#using-scikit-gstat) was not in dictionary format. If I just don't know, please provide examples.